# How to get right sidebar up on main content on resize of flexible with page?

Tags: css

I have page with main content and right sidebar. But I want to have sidebar before main content block on page resize. How can I accomplish this?

HTML part:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"></div>
</div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="content">
        main content
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        sidebar
    </div>            

</div>

<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
#container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    clear:both;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    padding: 2% 0;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 28%;
    float: right;
    padding: 2% 0;
}
```

Comment: You want the sidebar to displayed before the main content? As in both divs will be 100% width but right sidebar will be before main? On any page resize at all, or specifically a viewport size (are you trying to do responsive design)?

Comment: Yes. :-) I am using @media max-width to reorder content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to do responsive design, what you want to do is  media query in your CSS that will allow you to style the changes you want to make. The first decision you have to make is which screen sizes you want to display the responsive design. Tablets usually have a max-width of 760px and phones are around max-width of 480px. So the media query will look something like this:

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    ...all your mobile styles are in here...
}
```

Now to answer the positioning issues you have. Of course there are several ways, the way I would do it is this is to move your sidebar above the content in the HTML, remove the `clear` from the content CSS, and inside the media query all you have to do is make the width for both divs `100%`.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">The logo</div>
</div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="sidebar">
        sidebar
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        main content
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    background:grey;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    float:right;
    background:lightgrey;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    #sidebar {
        width:100%;
    }
    #content {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying it by this way before, but having forgotten clear on content. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your media query float your `#sidebar` left and your `#content` right.